# How to rotate in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, transpose

I have a data frame that looks like below and I want to rotate. I use `t()` function in R, but I the direction where I want to rotate the data frame is different from the desired output. Please find the snippet of my code below:

```
 x<-data.frame(x=c(1,4,5,6,7),y=c(5,7,8,5,9))

> x
  x y
1 1 5
2 4 7
3 5 8
4 6 5
5 7 9
> t(x)
  [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
x    1    4    5    6    7
y    5    7    8    5    9
```

Rather, i want the following output:

```
    [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
 y    5    7    8    5    9
 x    1    4    5    6    7
```

How can i achieve this in R?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can reverse and transpose at the same time

```
t(rev(x))
#   [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
# y    5    7    8    5    9
# x    1    4    5    6    7
```

Answer (score 0):

Reverse the column names, then rotate:

```
t(x[rev(names(x))])
```

Answer (score 0):

We can also use

```
 t(x[ncol(x):1])
```